# Elastica not grouping aggregation before setScript

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I have a type product in elasticsearch that contains a column containing multiple ids, some of them are the same. 
There are also columns containing current price and the quantity. I want the to get the sum of price * qte of each unique id.

```
id    price    qte
__    _____    _________

1    25        4
1    25        4
1    25        4
2    38        2
2    38        2
3    12        3
3    12        3
3    12        3
3    12        3
4    33        6
5    64        8
5    64        8
```

(if you're wondering why it's like that, it's cuz there are other columns with different values for each, also note that each unique id has a unique price and a unique quantity)

So I created my aggregation :

```
$id = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('id');
$id->setField('id')->setSize(0);

$qte_price = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Sum('qte_price');
$qte_price->setScript('doc["price"].value * doc["qte"].value');

$id->addAggregation($qte_price);
```

The problem here, is that `qte_price` doesn't use the first aggregation on the `id` before performing the `setScript()`, thus summing the total of `price * qte` on all ids even the repeated ones.

In other words I want to calculate for `id=1 => 25*4` (and not `(25*4)*3`, for `id=2 => 38*2` (and not `(38*2)*2)` .. etc

I found a trick to overcome this problem is by dividing the answer by the doc_count, but I'm looking for an official way of doing this using Elastica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `avg` aggregation for both the `price` and `qte` fields and then use a [`bucket_script` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) to multiply the average price by the average quantity and that would do what you expect.

The average of 3*25 is 25 and the average of 3*4 is 4, then you can multiply 25 by 4 and you get your answer for id = 1... The same goes for the other ids.

In pure DSL, it'd look like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_price": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "avg_qte": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "qte"
          }
        },
        "price_by_qte": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "avgPrice": "avg_price",
              "avgQte": "avg_qte"
            },
            "script": "params.avgPrice * params.avgQte"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expressed in Elastica, it would go like this:

```
$id = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('id');
$id->setField('id')->setSize(0);

$avg_price = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Avg('avg_price');
$avg_price->setField('price');
$id->addAggregation($avg_price);

$avg_qte = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Avg('avg_qte');
$avg_qte->setField('qte');
$id->addAggregation($avg_qte);

$bucketScriptAggregation = new BucketScript(
    'price_by_qte',
    [
        'avgPrice' => 'avg_price',
        'avgQte' => 'avg_qte',
    ],
    'params.avgPrice * params.avgQte'
);
$id->addAggregation($bucketScriptAggregation);
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround, but mine is better in term of performance (divide the answer of each unique id by the doc_count and thus getting the right result) as I only use 2 aggregations while yours uses 3 + a BucketScript agg. Isn't there a less hungry way to do so?

Comment: The difference is that the division by doc_count needs to be done in your app while my solution leverages ES fully in order to give you an exact answer to be used right away. I wouldn't be too concerned about the bucket script agg, it's only a way to perform a computation on already aggregated data, it's not something heavy.

Comment: Pipeline aggregations have been officially created to perform computations on aggregated results within ES and lighten the burden on client-side apps. Moreover, when talking about performance, one must always measure it on both solutions before drawing premature conclusions ;-)

Comment: In my case I prefer using my trick as it uses less aggregations, but your answer deserved the bounty and I'll keep it for reference if I ever need to do so only with elasticsearch. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've provided an "official way" as you asked ;-) Besides, have you measured the performance of both solutions?

Comment: oops I didn't notice, thanks for reminding me! And don't worry about the performance I managed :) Have a great day Val! :D